# Underbrace under minipage tables

Tags: minipage, underbrace

hope you are all fine.
I have been trying to construct a set of two tables using minipage and under both tables to place an underbrace with text. I have tried many different things but nothing seems to be working. I wonder if, for example, given the table I am pasting below, it is possible to place an underbrace with text below both tables.

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \caption*{Example}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \caption{some text here.}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{lll}
                       &         \begin{turn}{90}{{0}}  \end{turn}          &  \begin{turn}{90}{{18}}  \end{turn}                    \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{ {{1}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{{{0}} \phantom{\hspace{-1cm}\begin{turn}{45}{{0}}  \end{turn}} } & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{{{18}}} \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{ {{0}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{{{0}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{{{0}}  \phantom{\hspace{-1cm}\begin{turn}{45}{{0}}  \end{turn}}   } \\ \cline{2-3} 
\end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}%
            \begin{minipage}[3cm]{.1\linewidth}
\vspace{2cm}
\hspace{-1.0cm}{\resizebox{3cm}{!}{$\leadsto$}}
    \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
            \caption{ some other text here}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{lll}
                       &         \begin{turn}{90}{{0}}  \end{turn}          &  \begin{turn}{90}{{18}}  \end{turn}                    \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{ {{1}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{ {\color{red}\begin{turn}{45}{{0}}  \end{turn}}  } & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{ {{0}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{ {\color{red}  \begin{turn}{45}{{0}}  \end{turn} }} \\ \cline{2-3} 
\end{tabular}
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(13.25cm,9.0cm){ {\color{red} \begin{turn}{45}{{18}}  \end{turn}}  }\end{textblock*}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{table}
```

Another issue I'm facing is that the number 18, which is turn with with

```
begin{textblock*}{5cm}(13.25cm,9.0cm){ {\color{red} \begin{turn}{45}{{18}}  \end{turn}}  }\end{textblock*}
```

is under a textblock and every time I add or remove text before the table I need to re-adjust the coordinates of the position of "18", that is, 13.25cm,9.0cm. I wonder if it would be possible to set the coordinates that work for the minipage regardless of the changing text above.

Finally, I thought that

```
\leadsto
```

could be centred using `\hspace{-1.0cm}` but it seems that it can be either very left or very right but not centred.

Hope someone could bring some light into this very particular problem.

Im using fancy and document class book.
Thank you

I have been requested later to extend my question: I add a complete code that compiles

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%!TEX program = xelatex
%You can use xelatex, too
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}


\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}

\usepackage[backref,xetex=true,bookmarks=false,colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=FitV, linkcolor=blue,  citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue,pdfstartview=FitH]{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
    \caption*{Example}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \caption{some text here.}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{lll}
                       &         \begin{turn}{90}{{0}}  \end{turn}          &  \begin{turn}{90}{{18}}  \end{turn}                    \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{ {{1}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{{{0}} \phantom{\hspace{-1cm}\begin{turn}{45}{{0}}  \end{turn}} } & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{{{18}}} \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{ {{0}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{{{0}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{{{0}}  \phantom{\hspace{-1cm}\begin{turn}{45}{{0}}  \end{turn}}   } \\ \cline{2-3} 
\end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}%
            \begin{minipage}[3cm]{.1\linewidth}
\vspace{2cm}
\hspace{-1.0cm}{\resizebox{3cm}{!}{$\leadsto$}}
    \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
            \caption{ some other text here}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{lll}
                       &         \begin{turn}{90}{{0}}  \end{turn}          &  \begin{turn}{90}{{18}}  \end{turn}                    \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{ {{1}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{ {\color{red}\begin{turn}{45}{{0}}  \end{turn}}  } & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{ {{0}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{ {\color{red}  \begin{turn}{45}{{0}}  \end{turn} }} \\ \cline{2-3} 
\end{tabular}
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(13.25cm,9.0cm){ {\color{red} \begin{turn}{45}{{18}}  \end{turn}}  }\end{textblock*}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Now, the \usepackage{rotating} works for

```
\begin{turn}
```

Thank you

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete but small, compilable document, which we can compile as it is. Now `begin{turn}` is unknown ...

Comment: H,i I have added the conde to my question. Thanks